# How to handle new third party cookie rules starting in Chrome 80?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cross-browser, local-storage

Beginning with Chrome 80, third party cookies will be blocked unless they have `SameSite=None` and `Secure` as attributes. With `None` as a new value for that attribute. https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html

The above blog post states that Firefox and Edge plan on implementing these changes at an undetermined date. And there are is a list of incompatible browsers listed here https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients.

What would be the best practice for handling this situation for cross-browser compatibility?

An initial thought is to use local storage instead of a cookie but there is a concern that a similar change could happen with local storage in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit on the good point that as browsers move towards stronger methods of preserving user privacy this changes how sites need to consider handling data. There's definitely a tension between the composable / embeddable nature of the web and the privacy / security concerns of that mixed content. I think this is currently coming to the foreground in the conflict between locking down fingerprinting vectors to prevent user tracking that are often the same signals used by sites to detect fraud. The age old problem that if you have perfect privacy for "good" reasons, that means all the people doing "bad" things (like cycling through a batch of stolen credit cards) also have perfect privacy.

Anyway, outside the ethical dilemmas of all of this I would suggest finding ways to encourage users to have an intentional, first-party relationship with your site / service when you need to track some kind of state related to them. It feels like a generally safe assumption to code as if all storage will be partitioned in the long run and that any form of tracking should be via informed consent. If that's not the direction things go, then I still think you will have created a better experience.

In the short term, there are some options at https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes:

1. Use two sets of cookies, one with current format headers and one without to catch all browsers.
2. Sniff the useragent to return appropriate headers to the browser.

You can also maintain a first-party cookie, e.g. `SameSite=Lax` or `SameSite=Strict` that you use to refresh the cross-site cookies when the user visits your site in a top-level context. For example, if you provide an embeddable widget that gives personalised content, in the event there are no cookies you can display a message in the widget that links the user to the original site to sign in. That way you're explicitly communicating the value to your user of allowing them to be identified across this site boundary.

For a longer-term view, you can look at proposals like [HTTP State Tokens](https://github.com/mikewest/http-state-tokens) which outlines a single, client-controlled token with an explicit cross-site opt-in. There's also the [`isLoggedIn` proposal](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2019Sep/0004.html) which is concerned with providing a way of indicating to the browser that a specific token is used to track the user's session.